# Grouping Array by another array 'createdAt' values

Tags: arrays, angular, mapreduce

i have 2 arrays from my Api
this

```
passArray:[
{pass_id: 645, heure_debut: '13:48:00', heure_fin: '14:48:00', createdAt:"2023-08-03T13:48:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 646, heure_debut: '14:40:00', heure_fin: '15:40:00', createdAt:"2023-08-03T14:40:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 647, heure_debut: '20:30:00', heure_fin: '21:30:00', createdAt:"2023-08-04T20:30:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 648, heure_debut: '13:00:00', heure_fin: '14:00:00', createdAt:"2023-08-04T13:00:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 649, heure_debut: '16:25:00', heure_fin: '17:25:00', createdAt:"2023-08-05T16:25:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 650, heure_debut: '18:30:00', heure_fin: '19:30:00', createdAt:"2023-08-05T18:30:00.000Z"}

]
```

```
array2:[
{horaire_id: 5, operation: 'opened', user_id: 1, createdAt: '2023-08-03T12:15:46.000Z'}
{horaire_id: 7, operation: 'closed', user_id: 1, createdAt: '2023-08-04T12:21:29.000Z'}
{horaire_id: 8, operation: 'opened', user_id: 1, createdAt: '2023-08-04T12:29:04.000Z'}
{horaire_id: 9, operation: 'closed', user_id: 1, createdAt: '2023-08-05T07:57:16.000Z'}
{horaire_id: 10, operation: 'opened',user_id: 1, createdAt: '2023-08-05T08:04:48.000Z'}
{horaire_id: 11, operation: 'closed',user_id: 1, createdAt: '2023-08-06T03:06:56.000Z'}
]
```

i want to groupe passArray by 'createdAt' filtered by Array2 'createdAt' interval 'opened and closed'
i dont know if i must to use reduce or filter ?

I wish to have as a result something like that

```
2023-08-03T12:15:46.000Z :
{pass_id: 645, heure_debut: '13:48:00', heure_fin: '14:48:00', createdAt:"2023-08-03T13:48:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 646, heure_debut: '14:40:00', heure_fin: '15:40:00', createdAt:"2023-08-03T14:40:00.000Z"},

2023-08-04T12:29:04.000Z:
{pass_id: 647, heure_debut: '20:30:00', heure_fin: '21:30:00', createdAt:"2023-08-04T20:30:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 648, heure_debut: '13:00:00', heure_fin: '14:00:00', createdAt:"2023-08-04T13:00:00.000Z"}

2023-08-05T07:57:16.000Z:
{pass_id: 649, heure_debut: '16:25:00', heure_fin: '17:25:00', createdAt:"2023-08-05T16:25:00.000Z"}
{pass_id: 650, heure_debut: '18:30:00', heure_fin: '19:30:00', createdAt:"2023-08-05T18:30:00.000Z"}
```

the final goal is to obtain at the end the number of pass in passArray in an interval of opened and closed of array2.
thinks

reduce ? or filter ? or map ? i dont know

Comment: What do you have so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally, we'd be able to see what you have so far so we can offer advice or a potential solution from that. Since that is not present, I will give you an idea of what I would do to tackle this.

```
function groupPasses(passArray, array2) {
    // Create an array of the intervals from array2
    let intervals = [];
    for(let i = 0; i < array2.length; i += 2){
        if(array2[i] && array2[i+1]){
            intervals.push({
                start: new Date(array2[i].createdAt),
                end: new Date(array2[i+1].createdAt)
            });
        }
    }

    // Use reduce to create an object where the keys are the createdAt dates
    // and the values are arrays of elements from passArray that fall within the interval
    return passArray.reduce((acc, pass) => {
        let passDate = new Date(pass.createdAt);

        // Use filter to find the interval that the pass falls in
        let interval = intervals.filter((interval) => 
            passDate >= interval.start && passDate <= interval.end
        )[0];

        if(interval){
            let key = interval.start.toISOString();
            if(!acc[key]){
                acc[key] = [];
            }

            acc[key].push(pass);
        }

        return acc;
    }, {});
}
```

This function first creates an array of intervals from `array2`. Then it iterates over `passArray` using reduce. For each element in `passArray`, it uses `filter` to find the interval from `array2` that the element's `createdAt` date falls within. It then adds the element to the appropriate array in the object it's creating.

Remember to ensure that `array2` is sorted in ascending order by the `createdAt` property before using this function. This function assumes that every 'opened' operation in `array2` is followed by a 'closed' operation.

The final object created by this function will have keys that are the start dates of the intervals in `array2`, and the values are arrays of elements from `passArray` that fall within those intervals. You can get the number of passes in each interval by getting the length of these arrays.